# How to SELECT * with multiple WHERE using fetch_assoc in prepared statements in PHP-MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, associative-array, where-clause

It's been two days and I have not found any solution for this on Google, so please help.

I have to `SELECT *` from one row with multiple `WHERE` clauses, using a prepared statements, I want to retrieve the results using `fetch_assoc` so that I don't have to bind variables using `bind_result()`, using `fetch_assoc` I can print many columns as `$row['column_name']`. My code is below and it's not running, giving no error.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `uid` = ? AND `email` = ?';

if ($stmt_select = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt_select->bind_param('is', $user_id, $user_email);

  $user_id = $_SESSION['uid']; //this variable is set and prints perfectly
  $user_email = $_SESSION['user_email']; //this variable is set and prints perfectly

    $result = $stmt_select->execute();

    $stmt_select->store_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);
        echo  $row["supermarket_name"];
        echo $row["supermarket-region"];
        /*Nothing is being printed*/
    }

    $stmt_select->free_result();

$stmt_select->close();

}else{
    echo 'query returned false';
}
```

The `var_dump($result)` returns (boolean)true

Since the above code isn't throwing any error and in last two days I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code, can somebody let me know what's wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: What does `$stmt_select->error;` output? Did you enable general PHP error-reporting? Are there any rows returned at all, `$stmt_select->num_rows;`?

Comment: have you tried to print the query itself ? and checked if all correct ?

Comment: If the execute was successful, its likely that there were no rows returned. You still need to `execute()` (which would **always** return a boolean), but if there are no results, there's nothing to loop either. That won't affect the return value from `execute()` though.

Comment: @Qirel  `$stmt_select->error;` didn't print anything `$stmt_select->num_rows;` didn't print anything 
There are rows in the table, I can see this in phpmyadmin
@Demonyowh  I tried the query in phpmyadmin and it gives the desired results

All it's printing is `query returned false` as if the query is not correct, but it runs fine on phpmyadmin.

If execute is not used for fetching results what should be done for SELECT * in prepared statements?
@

Comment: Wait, you're saying that it didn't even prepare it? Since it printed "*query returned false*", the prepare failed - how can you then know what the execute returned?

Comment: @Qirel  `$result = $stmt_select->execute();` I did `var_dump($result);` and it returned `(boolean)true`

Comment: Yeah, but if you got "*query returned false*", then it never even entered that condition - meaning the *prepare* failed. Then you need to check for `$conn->error;` too.

Comment: you are defining `$user_id` and  `$user_email` after binding them, that might be a problem