# What is the correct way of printing results set by `SELECT *` with multiple `WHERE` clauses in prepared statements using `fetch_assoc()` in PHP-MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch, where-clause

My query is below:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `uid` = ? AND `email` = ?';
$stmt_select = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt_select->bind_param('is', $user_id, $user_email);
$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$result = $stmt_select->execute();
```

I want to print results set using `fetch_assoc`, this is because I don't want to `bind_result()` to all 23 columns' name, I want to print it using `$row['column_name']`, what is the correct way of achieving it?

If you want to see my code, I asked another question here:
[How to SELECT * with multiple WHERE using fetch_assoc in prepared statements in PHP-MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862980/how-to-select-with-multiple-where-using-fetch-assoc-in-prepared-statements-in)

But it didn't get answered correctly, so instead of correcting my code, can you tell me what's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: i hope my answer helped @user7984467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue using `SELECT *` in mysqli. The issue lies with the `bind_result` part. Normally you would need to add many variables. Meaning if you had about 20 columns, you would need 20 variables to include in the `bind_result` statement.

I've tailored my solution to fix your issues.

```
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `uid` = ? AND `email` = ?';
    $stmt_select = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt_select->bind_param('is', $user_id, $user_email);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
    $result = $stmt_select->execute();
   $stmt_select->store_result();//after this line we can output the number of rows if you need to check that as well
   $number_of_rows = $stmt_select->num_rows;
   $meta = $stmt_select ->result_metadata();
   $parameters = array();
  $results = array();
  while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
         $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
  }
  call_user_func_array(array($stmt_select , 'bind_result'), $parameters);
       while ($stmt_select ->fetch()) {
             foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                  $x[$key] = $val; //here we get the key => value (Column => Value)
                      }
                      $results[] = $x; //lets grab everything here
                  }
print_r($results);
```

Comment: This works as expected!! Wish you good luck with all your future projects!